# How can I use Cache during application bootstrapping?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am migrating a Laravel 4.2 application to Laravel 5.1.

During bootstrap, when loading the mail configuration file (`config/mail.php`), I want to read my SMTP configuration from DB and cache it.
In order to do that I use an Eloquent model class, in which I use the Cache facade's `remember()` function to get the data I need.

It used to work in 4.2, but after switching to 5.1, I get the following error message:

> Call to a member function remember() on a non-object

This happens after I put the following line at the top of the class:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;`

Without that line I got a `Class 'Cache' not found` error message.

Any idea what am I missing? Is this even possible in 5.1?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try just `use Cache;` instead, since it's a facade.

Comment: @JoelHinz when I use `use Cache` I both get an error in my IDE (PhpStorm) and a `Class 'Cache' not found` PHP error

Comment: where are you calling the cache during bootstrap? which script?

Comment: @yangqi during configuration loading (I guess it is during bootstrap, right?), in the `config/mail.php` script.

Comment: I'm seeing a related issue in 5.1 when I'm trying to use the Cache in my package. It should work as Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache is supposed to be global. All I see though is ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::get()``` so it looks as though something is broken in the process of loading the base cache/storage layer.

Comment: You have solved? I have the same problem ...